# How do I upload my uber-jar to a spark cluster created using the spark-ec2 scripts?

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I create an EC2 Spark cluster in one line of code using `SPARK_HOME/ec2/spark-ec2`

I'm also using `--copy-aws-credentials` (Spark 1.2.0) so `sc.textFile("s3...")` works well

My issue is silly, how do I copy my jar to the master?

1. aws cli doesn't seem to be setup correctly so I can't use s3 directly.
2. I can make the jar public and just wget it but this is bad practice.
3. I tried to connect to the master from the outside, but it's blocked

What is the best practice for submitting an uber jar to a spark standalone amazon ec2 cluster launched via `ec2/spark-ec2`?

Comment: You can use --jars option of spark-submit

Comment: Yes, I know :) but the jar is on s3, and I don't want to configure the master's AWS keys every time... I found out though that I can use sc.addJar and provide an hdfs or s3 location! but now my issue is that --copy-aws-credentials stopped working!